# How can I export and share my IDEA bookmarks and Favorites

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to export my IntelliJ IDEA favourites for backup, or to share with colleagues, like the way I can export my code formatting preferences (File > Export Settings)?

I'm working on a large codebase (one IDEA project), and have to switch between different new feature tasks and bug fixes, so I find it really convenient to create new Favourites list per Task or Jira ticket.

My Favourites tab is full with tens of favourite lists, and it's getting harder everyday to browse through them. So I could organise my work better if I could export them (ideally a different export per task, but grouping them is OK too), and reimport when I need to work on them again.

Any alternative suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: You can't export favorites and bookmarks, related requests: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-111619
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98138.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks! I'll wait for an alternative suggestion, before closing this

Answer (score 4):

@Eugene Morozov  Fortunately yes !

And I must admit that I'm very disappointed in the fact that there is no IntelliJ team support for this topic,
or some guidance to help people, as this happens pretty much after all new versions of IntelliJ and it's update,
and as a consequence, it impacts a developer's work, at least for us who work on really big projects.

So I've decided, to make this short tutorial how to restore back your bookmarks for Windows 10 users :

As of version 2020.1, IntelliJ operates under hidden Windows user AppData folder :
e.g. C:\Users<windows.user.name>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea\workspace

Even more, under C:\Users<windows.user.name>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains there are previous versions, (along with backup folders !)
and under appropriate version, in folder "workspace" there are all modifications, in the form of <funny_ssh_like_fileName>.xml
(e.g. 1lFTpsTT6pUo3tksBtYpwaD5qZ2.xml)

So, in my case, I've :

1. opened ~\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\workspace
2. sort files to descend based on modified flag
3. opened the newest one, and found that there is just one new bookmark, without previous ones !
4. so, I opened next recent xml, found  and copied everything in between,
   into the current IntelliJ workspace file

Comment: This works, but I wonder why the config isn't in `.idea/` folder in the project, rather in the `%AppData%`

Comment: Today is 08/19/22. The same problem is almost the same for a solution nowaday. I am using Pycharm Community. The path for WORKSPACE for me is:"AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.2\workspace" - Windows 10 Pro. With IDE closed, there, I got the newest funnyFile.xml, copy the blocks that refers to desired BookMark for replication wanted and replace the block <entry key="url"> for "<entry key="url" value="forTheNewFileName">. Later, just appended right after "</BookmarkState>" block. Opened the IDE and...the BOOKMARK was there pointing to the new file created before! :-)

Comment: If you are looking for the bookmarks on Android Studio for Mac, I found xml file  under the following location as of now AS Dolphin | 2001. 3. 1 ; `~\Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.3/workspace`

Comment: Mac Intellij: ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea{version}/workspace

Answer (score 0):

**(Note this answer may now be out of date)**

Bookmarks come under `<component name="BookmarkManager">` in the `.idea\workspace.xml`.  *(Since the answer was posted the location changed to `AppData`)*

But the problem is that:

- If you try to use the bookmarks on a file that has changed, the line numbers the bookmarks point to will likely have changed and the links are broken.

Comment: I've noticed that over time they tend to get misaligned anyway.

Comment: This is obsolete now. Have a look at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007607519/comments/360001396540

Comment: @AMArostegui, What are you getting at? (and your link refers to PyCharm)

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010224580-IntelliJ-Bookmarks-Favorites-Backup-restore-Windows-users